# send listview data to another listview and activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a problem with my android application.

I need to show all files from a folder which user 'chooses' from the listview.
It works well if i do that in one activity, but i need to make it show files from the chosen folder in other activity listview.

For example:

We go list of folders in listview in activity A

- Folders:
- test
- testfolder
- ...and more folders

For example folder "testfolder" contains text files so when i click on "testfolder" i need to show text files in listview of activity B

```
public class FolderActivity extends Activity {

EditText folderName;
ListView listView;
String CURRENT_FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/AppicationTest";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_folder);


    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);  


    createFolderOnStart();

    refreshDirectory();


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lista, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowFiles.class);

            File file = new File(CURRENT_FOLDER + "/" + lista.getItemAtPosition(position));                                     

            if(file.canRead()){
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    String[] list = file.list();

                    CURRENT_FOLDER += "/" + lista.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)); 

                    intent.putExtra("files", list);

                }
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code of first activity.

What should i do to make files display in listview of second activity?

Comment: Why do you have to send the complete list? Why don't you just send the parent in the Extra and retrieve the list of files from the next Activity? You can do it generically with just one Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the full path of the current selected folder to activity B by passing through intent.
   Parse the same in B activity and show the files